# Swap two shortcuts

Tags: key-bindings, navigation

I'm very new to vim and found bindings `Ctrl-F` for page down and `Ctrl-B` for page up kind of inconvenient. I intuitively try to page up with `Ctrl-F` and page down with `Ctrl-B` because `F` is higher than `B`.

***QUESTION:*** Is there a way to swap this two combinations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You can change just about anything you want to change in Vim. 
Just do

```
nnoremap <C-f> <C-b>
nnoremap <C-b> <C-f>
```

Add those two mappings in your `vimrc` file and you've both of those commands swapped.

`nnoremap` - Maps new key combinations to existing commands without affecting any other commands that might be using the original command.

The mnemonic for me is,

```
f - forward
b - backward
```

So, whenever I want to go forward in the page, I press `Ctrl + F` and `Ctrl + B` for going backward.

Comment: Its not just something I use. It is probably how the command was intended to be remembered as.

Comment: There are other ways to move around in the file; the keys ^F and ^B move forward and backward a page, keeping a couple of lines of continuity between screens so that it is possible to read through a file using these rather than ^Dand ^U if you wish.

Comment: This is from Bill Joy's original paper on vi.